# For SQL Server 2017 RS instance registry key value showing wrongly

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working with SSRS in SQL Server 2017 and facing issues due to a registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS

Key name: MyInstance
Key value: MyInstance
```

As per 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server document

Key value should be in following format `MSRS14.MyInstance`

Due to this change, code is breaking.

I need some clarity regarding SQL Server registry keys

Comment: I am not seeing a question here. How are you sure the registry entry is causing problems? Have you tried changing it and restarting the server to test?

Comment: I found out while debugging the code
and as per observation SQL 2016 and older versions follow the document so for those SQL versions key value is in this MSRSxx.MyInstance format but it is not true in SQL 2017, I found this strange so. I'm not sure whether it is right observation so I wanted some clarity regrading the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation and servicing methodology for Reporting Services has changed as of SQL 2017.  It's no longer included in the SQL Server installation media, and is no longer installed as a component of a SQL Instance.  It now uses a stand-alone installer, and doesn't support multiple instances.

As a consequence the file and registry paths have changed.

See the release announcement on the SSRS team blog for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/10/02/sql-server-2017-reporting-services-now-generally-available/

Comment: Thanks Devid, I was thinking same, so probably i need to modify my code to accommodate these changes